# .NET integration with Honeywell D6X00 Platform SDK ( for Personal digital assistant - Dolphin 6500 Mobile Computer application development )

Tags: .net, windows-ce, barcode-scanner, windows-mobile-6.5

I am planning to develop a *bar code scanning* application for Dolphin 6500 Mobile Computer using **Honeywell D6X00 Platform SDK**.

I have no idea, that how to develop app using Honeywell D6X00 Platform SDK in **.NET**

After googling i known to use Visual C# template called **Smart device**.

I created an app using that smart device template, but the application **cannot refer** the libraries ( .dll ) files in SDK.
 So, i am having many questions regarding these development,

- How to **integrate .NET with Honeywell D6X00 Platform SDK**( other than Visual c#- Smart device template )
- Sample codes or apps or links regarding the integration would be great.
- If Visual c#-smart device template is the correct way, then **is there any library** for **bar code scanning** and how to use the library?
- If library is present within the SDK, then how to use them to scan bar code?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's been a month since you posted yor question. And Still no answers. I'm having the same problem and I'd like to know if you've found something on your own that maybe you could share with the community. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, MiGU. No solution still.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw Thanks for your concern. Due to insufficient we hold that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is now several weeks old...
If you get a windows mobile device from any company and need an SDK for special hardware in the dvice, you first have to look for downloads at the company's web site.
For a Dolphin 6500, for example, you will find the possible downloads at https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/resources/Pages/download.aspx?pid=DOLPHIN6500.

To develop for a Windows Mobile (NOT Windows Phone!) you need a full VS2005 or 2008 version, the Express one's will not support SmartDevice development.

After you have downloaded and installed at least one Windows Mobile SDK by the MS sites. You are able to start a SmartDevice project in your VS setup. You can write C/C++, C# or VB.net SmartDevice projects (you can also mix the progr. languages). The company's SDK is only an extension to the MS WM SDK. Except for Windows CE powered devices, where the OEM have to provide a full platform SDK (the dolpin 6500 can be run with Windows CE 5 too! Watch your step.).

After you started a new SmartDevice .NET project, you can add a reference to the device's (company SDK) extensions. For example a barcoding assembly that offers objects, methods and events to handle barcode scanning.

I have seen the Honeywell SDK comes with a full doc and smaples for VB.NET and C#. These samples are starting points for you to start your own barcode-enabed projects.